# prevent from hide body scrollbar when show semantic ui modal

Tags: semantic-ui

i'm using semantic-ui framework for show modal.
problem is that when click button to show modal, first hide body scrollbar and later show modal and when close modal, body scrollbar show and page move to left .
now i need to prevent from hide body scrollbar when show modal. please help . tnx

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <i class="close icon"></i>
  <div class="header">
    Profile Picture
  </div>
  <div class="image content">
    <div class="ui medium image">
      <img src="/images/avatar/large/chris.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      <div class="ui header">We've auto-chosen a profile image for you.</div>
      <p>We've grabbed the following image from the <a href="https://www.gravatar.com" target="_blank">gravatar</a> image associated with your registered e-mail address.</p>
      <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Nope
    </div>
    <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
      Yep, that's me
      <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery statements is

```
$( ".nh-compare-page-title-sec" ).on( "click", function(){
      $('.ui.modal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: This prevents scrolling by dynamically setting classes on the body, so the easiest way to do this is probably to overwrite that with a more specific selector in your stylesheet.

Comment: tnx @04FS . solved by $("body").removeClass( 'dimmable' ).css('height' , 'auto'); after show modal ( semantic-ui v 2.4.1)